# get GitHub link for file in checkout in CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I'm looking for a bash script to generate a GitHub link to a file from the filename in my local checkout.

So if this script existed and was named `github-link-for-file`, it might work like this:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git
$ cd linux
$ github-link-for-file include/math-emu/quad.h
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/math-emu/quad.h
```

I expect that such a script already exists, but I can't find it. Can anyone else?

(If not, maybe I should write it and add it to a project like https://hub.github.com/. It looks like their "[`git browse`](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html)" command is very nearly what I want.)

Comment: IntelliJ can do this natively: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/viewing-the-github-version-of-a-file.html

Answer (score 3):

Should be pretty straightforward. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

URL=`git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/\.git//g'`
BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
FILE=$1

echo $URL/blob/$BRANCH/$FILE

exit 0
```

Save that to a Bash script file and remember to set it to executable with `chmod +x`.

You can then link the script file to an alias or symlink it in your `/usr/bin` directory. The script works relatively, so you will need to be inside of the repo directory when you run it.

Comment: That doesn't work, see the example given in the question. The GitHub URL for viewing a file starts "https://" and includes github-specific items like "/blob/". Your script gives "git:" urls and doesn't have "/blob/".

Comment: I believe the URL is based on how the repo was cloned, via SSH or HTTPS. I've tweaked the script to clean up the URL and also incorporate the branch name.

Comment: I usually clone via `git:`, not `https:`; I have clarified the question. I was really looking for a link to an existing project which did this, rather than a pair programming session to write and debug one. As I hinted in the question, I could write this for myself, but I'd prefer to grab one that works in all the edge cases I haven't thought of yet, like different `origin` URL forms.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [Gsinti's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1157267/399707) which supports remotes that are checked out via SSH

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_URL=$(git config --local remote.origin.url | cut -d "@" -f 2 | cut -d "." -f "1-2" | sed "s/:/\//")
URL="https://${GIT_URL}"
BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
FILE=$1

echo $URL/blob/$BRANCH/$FILE

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I have the same comment that I put on Gsinti's answer: As I hinted in the question, I could write this for myself, but I'd prefer to grab one from a library that works in all the edge cases I haven't thought of yet, like different origin URL forms.